# Raspberry Pi 3B ¿Cómo ejecutar programa al inicio? He probado todo y no lo consigo

Tags: python, raspberry

Hace un año aprox. conseguí muy fácilmente ejecutar un programa al iniciar la raspberry pi 3B.
No recuerdo con qué sistema, pero fue sencillo y funcionó a la primera.

Ahora quiero volver a hacerlo ejecutando un programa de Python y no lo consigo de ninguna de las formas explicadas. He probado 5 diferentes...

Me está volviendo loco y no sé qué puede estar fallando.
¿Alguien sabe si en este último año ha cambiado algo que no lo permita? Me extraña, no he visto nada en internet. Todas mis consultas me dirigen a las 5 formas de hacerlo...

- rc.local
- Cron (que no es exactamente lo que quiero)
- LXDE
- LXDE-pi
- systemd Daemon

He encontrado preguntas similares en este foro y aunque ya las había probado, he vuelto a intentarlo, pero no condigo que funcione.

Ojo, que he probado incluso a arrancar sencillamente "chromium" y tampoco lo he conseguido.
Si alguien me puede dar alguna pista, lo agradezco mucho.

Un cordial saludo y muchas gracias por adelantado.

---

Respondo a las preguntas de @CandidMoe:

Antes de nada, comentar que aunque he programado Arduino, Python y estoy acostumbrado a programas y configuraciones industriales, acabo de iniciarme en Raspberry.

Respondo a las preguntas:

**Lo primero ¿Qué distribución usas?**
No sé si te refieres al fabricante de la placa. Si es así, creo que es oficial.

- Pone ANATEL.
- La placa es Raspberry Pi 3B+
- Utilizo Raspbian o Raspberry Pi OS (recién descargado).

**¿Tienes configurado login automático?**
Sí, no me pide ni introduzco ni usuario ni password.

**¿Qué pusiste en rc.local?**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sudo bash /home/pi/di_update/Raspbian_For_Robots/upd_script/rc.sh
sudo python3 /home/pi/mypython.py &

exit 0
```

He ejecutado esa línea en el terminal y abre el programa perfectamente.

**¿Cómo configuraste el servicio con systemd?**
Primero creé el servicio:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/sample.service

[Unit]
Description=InicioPython
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/myphython.py &
Restart=always
User=pi
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Y luego lo recargué y lo habilité:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable sample.service
```

**¿Qué te arroja systemctl status?**
No hice esa prueba. La acabo de hacer y esto es lo que responde, que no sé interpretar:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status sample.service


● sample.service - InicioPython
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sample.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-10-13 18:34:25 CEST; 3s ago
 Main PID: 1460 (python3)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 2059)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sample.service
           └─1460 /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/mypython.py &

oct 13 18:34:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started InicioPython.
lines 1-9/9 (END)
```

He vuelto a probar estas dos formas y nada, no lo consigo.

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué distribución usas? ¿Tienes configurado login automático? ¿Qué pusistes en rc.local? ¿Cómo configurastes el servicio con systemd? ¿Qué te arroja systemctl status?

Comment: Te respondo punto por punto a tus preguntas, pero lo hago editando la pregunta, ya que aquí no entra, por espacio. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para incluir esa información donde todos la puedan ver.

Comment: Yo tenia ese problema y lo solucione usando `cron` el único inconveniente que tuve con esp es que cosas del propio S.O. ni estaban cargadas al momento de ejecutar el script pero lo solucione con un `sleep`

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo los mismos inconvenientes, aunque pude correr
un pequeño scrip realizando los siguientes pasos

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ mkdir ./bin

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cd ./bin 

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo nano nombre_del_script

en el editor poner:

#!/bin/bash
#script para arrancar nuestra aplicacion


python /home/pi/nombre_proyecto.py &

PARA SALIR : Ctrl+X, " Y", ENTER

para hacer que el script sea ejecutable hacemos:

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo chmod 755 nombre_del_script

para probar el script:

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ nombre_del_script
ejemplo: 

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ scrib.sh



Ahora para que arranque cuando conectamos la raspi:

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo nano /etc/rc.local

y agregar esto en el editor:

/home/pi/bin/nombre_del_script.sh

Ctrl+X, " Y", ENTER

luego hacer un reset:


Este es mi scrip # envia un mensaje a telegram

TOKEN="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
ID="XXXXXXXXXXX"
MENSAJE="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendMessage"

curl -s -X POST $URL -d chat_id=$ID -d text="$MENSAJE"
```

suerte

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/376132)